Single origin coffee or a blend? Which has a better quality?
Anyone has expertise which kind of coffee has a better quality? Most say that some brands rather do a special blend which creates a specific taste, from my experience most blends I tried didn't seem to have a special taste, single origin is also sometimes tricky to find and most studies pretend that single origin is healthier, is it true? Which brands are worth to consider? I tried myself Honduras Golden Coffee and didn't notice a great difference, though. I'd be interested to hear a more scientific point of view.

Coffee quality is determined by the bean freshness and other harvesting factors. Single origin coffees are generally considered "premium" so many roasters use higher quality beans for those. But it is possible for a blend to have high quality beans as well. Keep trying different options and see what you like.
